# AJAX "success" executing before response is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm hoping this is just a simple fix due to me being a little dumb somewhere along the line. I'm executing my ASP.NET MVC login using AJAX. There is a "success" handler which returns a "true" value to the calling function which, in turn, load the home page.

The issue is that the "success" handler is executing BEFORE any value is returned - which means that nothing happens because the value is not "SUCCESS". I can confirm this by looking at the request in Firebug, the value returned is SUCCESS but nothing happens. If I apply a breakpoint to the end of the function and then continue execution it works just fine.

I have no idea what the issue is, I'd be very grateful for help or an explanation to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

My JS Function:

```
function LogIn(UserName, Password) {
var Cont = true;
var ErrorString = "";
if (UserName == null || UserName == "") {
    Cont = false;
    ErrorString += "Username is Required.";
}
if (Password == null || Password == "") {
    Cont = false;
    ErrorString += "Password is Required.";
}

var result = false;

if (Cont) {
    var LogInUrl = "/AJAX/LogIn?UserName=" + UserName + "&Password=" + Password;
    $.ajax({
        url: LogInUrl,
        type:"GET",
        success: function( data ){
            if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    })
}

return result;
```

}

UPDATE: The function that calls the LogIn function:

```
$('#FormLogin').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var UserName = $("#TxtLoginUsername").val();
    var Password = $("#TxtLoginPassword").val();
    var IsLoggedIn = LogIn(UserName, Password);
    if (IsLoggedIn) {
        window.location.assign("/");
    } else {
        $('#LoginErrorContainer').show();
        $('#LoginErrorContainer .error-text').html("There was a problem logging you in. Please try again.");
    }
})
```

As I said, the function does it's job and logs me in, but the "success" handler seems to execute before the value is returned.

Comment: You appear to be missing a semicolon at the end of your ajax call.

Comment: The first "A" in "ajax" means "asynchronous".  Ihe `$.ajax` call returns **immediately** and the "success" callback is invoked when the HTTP request completes some time later.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Thanks for pointing that out, but it didn't repair the issue. Jonathan M If I had a break point to the end of the LogIn function, wait for the execution to hit the point, wait a few seconds then continue it works just fine.

Comment: Your success function is not executing before the value is returned, you are returning from your function before the value is returned. That is the problem as @Pointy alluded to.

Comment: I see, so the execution isn't linear as such when it comes to AJAX - I suppose it was quite naive of me to think that given the whole point of AJAX is to be Asynchronous. Thank you for that!

Comment: @KallumTanton: Not linear is pretty much exactly what *asynchronous* means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ajax call to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: LogInUrl,
    type:"GET",
    success: function( data ){
        if (data == "SUCCESS") {
            window.location.assign("/");
        } else {
            $('#LoginErrorContainer').show();
            $('#LoginErrorContainer .error-text').html("There was a problem logging you in. Please try again.");
        }
    }
});
```

There is no point in returning `result` from `LogIn`, it'll always be false. You need to put the code handling the returned value *in the callback*.

Another alternative, if you don't like the idea of your `LogIn` function being so closely coupled to DOM manipulation is to return the promise from your ajax call. So at the end of `LogIn`, you'd do something like this:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: LogInUrl,
    type:"GET"
    }
});
```

And then when you call it, you'd do something like this:

```
LogIn(UserName, Password).then(function(data) {
    if (data == "SUCCESS") {
        window.location.assign("/");
    } else {
        $('#LoginErrorContainer').show();
        $('#LoginErrorContainer .error-text').html("There was a problem logging you in. Please try again.");
    }
});
```